# Getting value from a form input in a javascript variable here I am using jquery cdn. please review code

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, input

I tried to save value of form input into a javascript varible but value is always undefind...

here is sample code

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter your name">
    <input type="email" name="address" id="address" placeholder="enter your mail address">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    <div id="id0">

    </div>

    <script>
        var a;
    
      a =$('input');
      var i=0;
      var c;
      var temp=document.getElementById("name").value;
      var temp1=document.getElementById("address").value;
   
      a.eq(2).on('click', function(){
        alert(temp)
    
        c=document.getElementById('id'+i);
        i++;
        c.innerHTML="<hr> Hi,   "+temp+"     Your address is    "+temp1+"<div id='id"+i+"'></div>";
        })

   </script>
</body>
```

Result:
Shown in image.

Just value of temp and temp1 varibales.

Comment: Move the 2 lines with `temp` and `temp1` down into your click function. Problem is that when you code is running the `temp` and `temp1` will be empty because at the time the variables are filled, the input's contain no data.

Comment: as suggested already you are fetching the name and address input values at page load when those field are still empty while you should do it inside the click event handler. I suggest you also: instead of using `.eq(2)` to fetch the button in the list of inputs, get the element directly doing `document.querySelector('input[name=submit]')`; to get rid of jQuery for select element***S*** use `querySelectorAll` and for adding the click event handler `addEventListener`; use template string literals instead of concatenating strings; change your input type submit to input type button;

Answer (score 0):

The variables `temp` and `temp1` Are taken as empty values since you are filling them from the `text inputs` before you enter some values in them, So to have the values from the `inputs` at the moment when you click your button you should fill the two variables `temp` and `temp1` in the click function like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="enter your name">
    <input type="email" name="address" id="address" placeholder="enter your mail address">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    <div id="id0"></div>

    <script>
      var a;
    
      a = $('input');
      var i=0;
      var c;
      
      a.eq(2).on('click', function(){
        var temp=document.getElementById("name").value;
        var temp1=document.getElementById("address").value;
        alert(temp);
    
        c=document.getElementById('id'+i);
        i++;
        c.innerHTML="<hr> Hi,   "+temp+"     Your address is    "+temp1+"<div id='id"+i+"'></div>";
        })
   </script>
</body>
```